# How to build a string to dynamically access a .resx resource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am wondering how I can dynamically build a string to reference a string in my Resources.resx file? I basically want to do the equivalent of the following in XAML:

This is so I can get the resource titled `ToyBlockName` or `ToyBallName`, which should come from the resx so it can be translated if necessary. I then hope to plug in those individual strings into formats of other strings. There are many strings that use these names, so it would be best if I could replace the single words rather than having a version of each string for each kind of toy I have.

Some example strings are `The {0} comes in a box.`, `The {0} costs only a few dollars.`

Essentially trying to do this in XAML:

```
String.Format(Properties.Resources.Default["ToyComesInBox"],
    Properties.Resources.Default["Toy" + Constants.ToyName + "Name"]);
```

(Where ToyName = "Block" or "Ball", etc)

Is there a way to accomplish this in XAML, or is there some other method I am not thinking of?

Comment: Why do it in XAML if you have a solution in C#?

Comment: Just trying to keep code out of the code-behind. I could just set these strings when initializing the windows/controls but I am curious to see if there is a pure-XAML way to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to do this with XAML only but we're doing it with converter/s. It can become quite messy however if you design it better than me it has even more potential, and it makes the code better IMO.

```
public class LocalizationConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object value, 
        Type targetType, 
        object parameter, 
        string language)
    {
        string valueString = value as string;
        var paramString = parameter as string;

        //so here you have the value of your binding in the value string
        //and if it's empty (because you don't want to use the bound value
        //you're setting the value string to be the param string

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(valueString))
        {
            valueString = paramString;
        }

        //if value string (formerly your param string is empty just return
        //there is no value to be found
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(valueString))
        {
            return null;
        }

        //now the fun starts :) ,I pass values with small command and 
        //separator symbol to be able to parse my parameters
        //something like this:
        //if (paramString.StartsWith("AddAfter|"))
        //{
        //    var valToAppend = paramString.Substring("AddAfter|".Length);
        //    return Strings.Get(Strings.Get(valToAppend + valueString));
        //}
        //and this basically does -> append the given parameter string after 
        //the part with the command to the value that comes from the binding
        //and then uses the resulting string from res dictionary 

        //So you could do something like passing "ToyType|Block" or you can
        //pass something in the value like Block and then in the parameters
        //have description ToyType or even pass not string object and get
        //what you want from it like
        //if(value is ToyType)
        //{
        //    return StringsGet((value as ToyType).Name)
        //}


        //Your parsing logic HERE



        //This is how we get strings from resources in our project
        //that you already know how to do

        return Strings.Get(valueString);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
        object value,
        Type targetType, 
        object parameter, 
        string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}
```

**Usage**

Define in resources (page or global)

```
<converters:LocalizationConverter x:Key="Loc" />
```

Use in XAML

Value only from parameters (string in this case)

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding 
                  Converter={StaticResource Loc},
                  ConverterParameter=ToyBlockName}" />
```

Or value only from bound variable (could be any kind of object)

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ToyBlockNameBoundValue 
                  Converter={StaticResource Loc}}" />
```

Or value from bound variable + complex parameter that could be parsed

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeBoundValue 
                  Converter={StaticResource Loc},
                  ConverterParameter=SomeMoreComplex|Parameter}" />
```