# CustomControl Controls in Properties?

Tags: wpf

is it possible to create a custom control, define it's style ect, and then when using the control add other controls into it's properties. Hard to explain, so here is some example code, clearly doesn't work, just so you can see what i'm trying to do:

```
<Controls:TitleContainer>
            <!-- Title Bar -->
            <Controls:TitleContainer.Title>
                <TextBlock>i Information</TextBlock>
            </Controls:TitleContainer.Title>
            <Controls:TitleContainer.Sub>
                <Button Style="{StaticResource BtnSmBlue}" Content="Search" />
            </Controls:TitleContainer.Sub>

            <!-- Main Content -->
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="any text here... blah blah" />
                <Button Content="Buttons" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Controls:TitleContainer>
```

I want to make a control like shown below, the container which has a title and some have an extra button to the right of the title, then obviously the content.

What's the best way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Just an idea: did you have a look at the HeaderedContentControl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @gomi42 suggested I was curious to test the control and here's some very simplified example, you will not use it that way at the end but you may start with it and add your bindings later.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="HeaderTemplate1">
        <Grid Background="DarkGray">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="150"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border Width="30" Height="30" Background="AliceBlue" Grid.Column="0"></Border>
            <TextBlock Text="SomeHeader" Foreground=" White" Grid.Column="1"></TextBlock>
            <ComboBox Grid.Column="2" SelectedIndex="0" Foreground="Green">
                <ComboBoxItem>item1</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>item2</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>item3</ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="HeaderTemplate2">
        <Grid Background="DarkGray">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="300"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border Width="30" Height="30" Background="AliceBlue" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="SomeHeader" Foreground=" White" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Background="Green" Foreground="White" Text="Asd"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Border Width="30" Height="30" Background="AliceBlue"/>
            <TextBlock Background="Red" Text="Some Button"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ContentTemplate1">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="Purple">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="Prop1" Foreground="White"/>
                <ProgressBar Grid.Column="1" Height="10" Value="35" Background="Purple" Foreground="GreenYellow" IsIndeterminate="False" Minimum="0" Maximum="100"/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="Prop2" Foreground="White"/>
                <ProgressBar Grid.Column="1" Height="10" Value="75" Background="Purple" Foreground="GreenYellow" IsIndeterminate="False" Minimum="0" Maximum="100"/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="Prop3" Foreground="White"/>
                <ProgressBar Grid.Column="1" Height="10" Value="15" Background="Purple" Foreground="GreenYellow" IsIndeterminate="False" Minimum="0" Maximum="100"/>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ContentTemplate2">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Purple">
            <Button Background="Green" Margin="10" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}"/>
            <Button Background="Green" Margin="10" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}"/>
            <Button Background="Green" Margin="10" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Background="Gray">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <HeaderedContentControl HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderTemplate1}" 
                            ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ContentTemplate1}"
                            Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10"/>
    <HeaderedContentControl HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderTemplate1}" 
                            ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ContentTemplate1}"
                            Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10"/>
    <HeaderedContentControl HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderTemplate2}" 
                            ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ContentTemplate2}"
                            Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10"/>
</Grid>
```

**Edit you could use this with custom control also**

We create a custom control like this - extending `HeaderedContentControl`, and setting it's background as yellow (just so that we can test easily)

```
public partial class CustomControl1 : HeaderedContentControl
{
    public CustomControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Background = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromRgb(255,255,0));
    }
}
```

We use the controls the same way in Xaml but this time we use our custom control

```
...
<local:CustomControl1 HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderTemplate1}" 
                            ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ContentTemplate1}"
                            Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10"/>
    <local:CustomControl1 HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderTemplate1}" 
                            ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ContentTemplate1}"
                            Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10"/>
    <local:CustomControl1 HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderTemplate2}"
                            ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ContentTemplate2}"
                            Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10"/>
...
```

Only this time with a different **ContentTemplate2** - Note the binding of it's background, it now takes the background property from it's parent (our custom control)

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ContentTemplate2">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
                    Background="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=HeaderedContentControl}}">
            <Button Background="Green" Margin="10" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}"/>
            <Button Background="Green" Margin="10" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}"/>
            <Button Background="Green" Margin="10" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: The main issue with this is that I don't want to hard-code the header text ect in the WindowResources, i'd like to have the template and then change the header text within the Control Definition.

Comment: You can do it if you give data context to your control, you could just bind the required text field to some value from the context and use localization converter (I've used such converter in a project). You provide some resource key in the view model and bind to it, then you get the actual value from resources in the converter.

Comment: I've done an edit that uses a background set from the custom control with binding inside the `DataTemplate`, also you could check this:  [How I use my localization converters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33376469/3878458) this is an answer on some other question and it is not 100% applicable for you but it might give you an idea. (used in WinRT project)

Comment: Thanks, I will likely use this `HeaderedContentControl ` in a way.

Comment: Np, the idea was @gomi42 's so credit to him, this control has potential. As for localization it's very easy to use simple converter and it save's a lot of time you just have to bind to resource keys instead of actual values, and makes the code in view models a lot cleaner in my opinion.